# bypass 'google before you continue' pop-up

Tags: popup

My code:

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from time import sleep
from pywebio import start_server
print("News web application successfully started!")
def app():
    request = requests.get("https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqRggKIkBDQklTS2pvUVkyOTJhV1JmZEdWNGRGOXhkV1Z5ZVlJQkZRb0lMMjB2TURKcU56RVNDUzl0THpBeFkzQjVlU2dBUAE/sections/CAQqSggAKkYICiJAQ0JJU0tqb1FZMjkyYVdSZmRHVjRkRjl4ZFdWeWVZSUJGUW9JTDIwdk1ESnFOekVTQ1M5dEx6QXhZM0I1ZVNnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen")
    content = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
    find = content.find('div', class_='ajwQHc BL5WZb')
    #open('test.html', 'w').write(findstr.find)
    h3 = find.find_all('h3')
    time = find.find_all('time')
    link = find.find_all('article')#.find_all('a').get('href').replace('.', '')
    result = []
    #print('https://news.google.com' + link)
    #put_html('<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">')
    source = find.find_all('a', {'data-n-tid' : '9'})
    time = find.find_all('time')
    textoutput = []
    textoutput1 = []
    textoutput2 = []
    takeoutput3 = []
    #writer = open('news.csv', 'w')
    #writer1 = csv.writer(writer, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for text in h3:
        a1 = text.text
        textoutput.append(a1)
    for text2 in source:
        a3 = text2.text
        textoutput1.append(a3)
    for text1 in time:
        a5 = text1.text
        textoutput2.append(a5)          
    #for result in link:
    #    alinks = result.find_all('a')
    #    alinks1 = []
    #    for alinks1 in alinks:
    #        alinks2 = alinks1.get('href')
    #        alinksreplace = str(alinks2)
    #        alinksreplace1 = alinksreplace.replace(".", "")
    #        alinksreplace2 = alinksreplace1.replace("None", "")
    #
    #        if (alinksreplace2 != ''):
    #            if "publications" not in alinksreplace2:
    #                a =  "https://news.google.com" + alinksreplace2
    #                takeoutput3.append(a)

    pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
    frame = {'Title':textoutput, 'Time':textoutput2, 'Source' : textoutput1}
    frame1 = pandas.DataFrame(frame)
    #frame2 = {'Link' : takeoutput3}
    #frame3 = pandas.DataFrame(frame2)
    frametostring = frame1.to_string(index=False)
    #frametostring1 = frame3.to_string(index=False)
    #print(frametostring)
    put_code(frametostring)
    #put_code(frametostring1)
    #writer1.writerow([textoutput, textoutput1, textoutput2])
start_server(app, 82)
```

it worked fine but today Google update something and now it don't start. And it's because Google add before you continue pop-up. How I can bypass this so my script continue to work?
If it was Selenium I've just clicked the button but here I don't know what to do

Thanks you helping!